# Another problem with 404 in pagination WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

I read so many articles and didnt find answer.

my custom product loop in category:

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
global $post;
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 6,
'product_cat' => $post->post_name, // **The father category**
'post_type' => 'product',
'paged' => $paged,
'page' => $page,
'pagination' => true
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $loop->request;
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    ?>

////////////////// product info//////////////

    <?php endwhile;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
    ) );
} else {
    echo __( 'No products found' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

in category page i have same link:

http://localhost:3000/product-category/cats/videocard/

pagination link:
http://localhost:3000/product-category/cats/videocard/page/2/

but i have 404 on it.

my permalink settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1swJ.png)

my "Read" settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bdas.png)

What i do wrong?

Comment: i add this rule in .htaccess RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /?page=$1 [L] and if i go to http://localhost:3000/product-category/cats/videocard/?page=2 i see page 2. How can i get equal result in localhost:3000/product-category/cats/videocard/page/2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your problem is related to the **WP_Query** arguments. I have spotted the following issues:

- the **'pagination'** is not a valid argument,
- the taxonomy argument ( **'product_cat'** ) given as key is deprecated, you should use **'tax_query'** instead.
- the **$page** variable value is not defined ( at least not in your sample script ) and it seems that the definition of both **'page'** and **'paged'** arguments might cause conflicts to your query.

Try using the following:

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $post->post_name // !
        ),
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
// echo $loop->request;  - I guess this is a test left-over
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        /**
         * No need to call the $product global within the loop,
         * use the $loop->post or even better call the product object
         * using the WooCommerce wc_get_product() function as displayed
         * below
         */
        // global $product;
        $product = wc_get_product( $loop->post );
    ?>

////////////////// product info//////////////

    <?php endwhile;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total'   => $loop->max_num_pages
    ) );

} else {

    echo __( 'No products found' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Last, but not least, the taxonomy term value you are giving for product_cat ( commented as *the father category* ) is the current post slug. I understand why you might want to do this, but under some circumstances, this could be also the reason you are getting these 404s. Therefore, if the above script is not solving your problem, I would advise you to look into this too.

Comment: nothing to change. links like http://localhost:3000/product-category/cats/videocard/page/2/ give 404 error

Comment: if i use woocommerce shortcode - pagination link seem like http://localhost:3000/product-category/cats/videocard/?product-page=2, but this link dont paginate in custom loop